# How to Handle Rails/Mongoid with no doc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nomethoderror

When calling all posts for a user `Posts.find(creator: current_user:_id)`, and the user hasn't made any...rails spits a "NoMethodError" for it...

What I want to do is have a pretty output for the user of "Why, no. You haven't posted anything, you lazy slob." instead of this scary error.

What's the best way to handle things like this?

Comment: If you prefer `find` to return `nil` instead of raising an exception, you can set `raise_not_found_error: false` in your `mongoid.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `where` instead of `find`. By design, `find` method expect to actually **find** an existing thing you're looking for. Consult docs about querying [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html).

Also, you can try and use `try` method. Basically it's equal to the following:

```
object.try(:something_scary)
# is equal to
object && object.something_scary
```

This is how I handle `nil` entities. If you want to show some kind of message to user (about being slobby) you make a check inside of your template and render different partials. Example:

```
   <% if @posts.present? %>
     <%= render 'posts' %>
   <% else %>
     <%= render 'no_posts' %>
   <% end %>
```

Then you can put your message inside of that `no_posts` partial.

Comment: Sorry, I'm misunderstanding my own post. It's return nill because I'm calling `Post.where(bla).first.post`...can you show me the best way to handle blank fields?? That's probably what I'm asking...

Comment: I'm giving you the check because you answered my question...I gave very vague details...so well done. I had to mess with this a lot given I have two models: `User` and `Posts`. Posts belong to User and user has_one post, so given that, I refactored my controller with an `if current_user.post?` and it did the trick. :)